# Issue with FIO in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

My computer seems to be unable to run file IO through Visual Studio 2022. I have an extremely basic file IO code that looks for a file `test.txt` within the `bin/debug/net8.0` directory and it is unable to see it. I'm having a hard time finding any documentation online for this issue.

Here is the code that I'm running:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Specify the path to the text file
        string filePath = "test.txt";

        try
        {
            // Read all lines from the file
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);

            // Display each line on the console
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"File not found: {filePath}");
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred while reading the file: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the message given in the terminal window:

> File not found: test.txt

I promise there is a file named `test.txt` there, and I even had someone test this exact code on their machine and it works.

Is there a setting or something that I need to change that might be stopping it from working?

Comment: Relative paths are resolved to your current working directory which is not necessarily the same as the location of the exe. By default it's the same as your top level directory that contains the sln if run inside VS.

Comment: Run `procmon` - does the _full_ path your program actually loads match the file's location on-disk? You say it's in the `Debug` directory but are you running Release? Did the file get deleted between deployments? Is the txt file listed as a `<Content>` file in your `.csproj`?

Comment: When you run a console app from Visual Studio (with either F5 or ctrl-F5), the current directory for the console app is the directory the .exe file is in (e.g. `bin/debug/net8.0`). You can verify by adding a `Console.WriteLine(Environment.CurrentDirectory);` line in your console app.

Comment: Is the `test.txt` file part of the project? Is the file in the project directory? In the file properties in the project is the `test.txt` file set with a "Build Action" of `none` or `content` and is "Copy to Output Directory" set to `Copy if newer`?

Comment: When you run a program from Visual Studio, the working directory is usually set to the project directory, not the bin/debug/net8.0 directory.